# Download File from secret path

Tags: php

I've got some confidential files(PDFs, and DOCx files) in a directory and anyone that uploads one of those, he can just do something like url/uploads/my_file.pdf and the file will download.

Therefore I decided I should create a script that generates each user a unique string and that will enable him to download the file.

My question is: what is the proper way to achieve this? 
Should I use readfile()? Should I create a unique folder path for each user? I really have no idea.

I'd appreciate any ideas/examples/code already written.

Thanks!

Comment: which technology do you want to use to create a script?

Answer (score 0):

Point browser to a script which writes the file contents to a file buffer. A simple shell script can be `example.extension > aRandomfile`

Use the readfile() function to read this buffer. Find the documentation at https://www.php.net/readfile